# why this C program is working

Tags: c, arrays

i have not created the array name then why this C program is working.`

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
  printf("%c",7["sundaram"]);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because `a[b]` is the same as `b[a]`. There are duplicates out there.

Comment: @juanchopanza but "sundaram" is not array name.it is just a content in that array.and i have not mention array name also

Comment: But you can apply `operator[]` to a pointer, and "sundaram" decays to pointer to `char`.

Comment: @Walter: the string literal decays into something like a `const char*`.

Comment: More like a `const char[8]`